# "required" bootstrap attribute on magicSuggest field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magicsuggest

i try to appear the bootstrap's tooltip "required" on magicSuggest field.

```
<input type="text" name="data-category" id="data-category" required>

//magic suggest 
        $(function() {
            var ms = $('#data-category').magicSuggest({
                allowFreeEntries: false,
                valueField: 'data_categorie_referential_data_id',
                displayField: 'data_categorie_referential_data_name',
                maxSelection: 1
            });
            $(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e, m){
                var valueSelected = ms.getValue();
                $('#data-category').val(valueSelected[0]);
            });
            ms.setData(<?php echo $data_category_list ?>);
        });
```

the attribute "required" doesn't work if nothing is selected and the form is submited.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `bootstrap's tooltip "required"`.

Comment: @10101010 on a classic input select, when you do not select an option, the form submission is blocked and tooltip appear if bootstrap run. It does not work on an input with magic suggest